# What is the preferred way to allow the same data set to be available to Windows 8 applications and to Windows Phone 8 applications?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing two applications: a Windows 8 application and a Windows Phone 8 application. Both applications should use the same data set.
I would like multiple users to be able to access and use the data (read and write) from either type of the applications.

Other than Azure, what would be the recommended ways to accomplish it?
The Data Set will grow over time.

Thanks,
Eitan B

Comment: curious as to why the "other than Azure" option - you'll be using a cloud here no matter what, and mobile integration with Azure is pretty sweet :)

Comment: Azure Mobile Services would be my choice, however I have no experience in estimating the cost. Have you used it? If so maybe you can share with me some pointers I should consider in terms of the cost.

Comment: well it's free at the moment since it's in preview, but you can read the [pricing details](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/).  Cost, of course will depend on usage, number of customers, etc., but unless you want to manage your own server, backups, etc., the cloud is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data will differ from user to user than you should use `SkyDrive` to store the each user's data in their `SkyDrive`, otherwise you have to use your own server to store all the data. Even if you use your own server, you can use `Live SDK` so that users can login using their `Microsoft Account`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I would like multiple people to use the same data. I am afraid to get into Azure Mobile because of the cost involved.

Comment: you can use other services like Amazon AWA or Rackspace. Having elastic storage option will be better.

Comment: I will look into that,
Thanks,Eitan